# Build Static Library in XCode 4 for iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator

I can build a static library in XCode 4 using the iOS Device scheme but not the iPhone Simulator scheme. It says "Build succeeded" but I do not see the requisite .a file magically appear under Products. If I choose the iOS Device scheme I see the .a file. I know I'm missing something obvious here, please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your build directory, if there's a *.a file in Release-iphonesimulator and Release-iphoneos then everything should be fine. But do you really need to use separate schemes? [Here's very good guide to static libraries on Xcode 4](http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/15/how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4/). This guide describes how to make libraries universal, so *.a files for simulator and device are merged into one single file.

Comment: I am facing the similar issue. In my case my .a library file is present in Release-iphonesimulator & Release-iphoneos directories. I can see only library file built for device in the Products section on the xCode4 & not the library file build for simulator. I am newbie to the iPhone development. It would be really great if someone can give me some hint about this behavior.